# Can I change the order of these columns in CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have multiple lists of data, made up of unordered lists in HTML and I'm trying to get them to display in 2 columns.

I've got them appearing as 'columns' but I can't get the columns to display how I want them to.

If you look at the below snippet you can see that the columns are aligned in 2 columns, but I'd like the columns to be sequential, so A, B, C, D in the left column and D, E, F etc in the right column.

I've used Flexbox and have been messing around with `flex-direction` but to no avail. Any tips? What am I doing wrong? Also, here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wb6528yg/).

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul li {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
</ul>
```

I know that this is something silly and trivial but what am I missing? I'm using Sass too.

Comment: Do you really need to have your `li`s ordered in your HTML? If so, you still can use CSS parity rules: `ul:nth-child(even) { /* even rows */ }` / `ul:nth-child(odd) { /* odd rows */ }`

Comment: @Kaddath the data that I'm showing is in alphabetical order and it's a requirement to have them ordered like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do this without setting the height of the element, which you may not want to do.

You can, however, use `column-count` to set a number of columns and it will make each column contain around the same number of items.

```css
ul {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 35px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with display : flex in IE, i suggest you use this code will work with every browser:

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't displaying them in columns, you are displaying them in rows that wrap.

If you need a column format **in flexbox** you need to use `flex-direction:column` AND set a height so that the flexbox knows when to wrap.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `flex-direction: column;` for that. But you also have to set a fixed height in that case.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 80px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul li {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex-direction: column;` and a height on the `ul`. This way the flex items are arranged top down instead of left to right (a row). The height makes sure the column wraps. Which is required if you want to use flexbox to do this.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 75px;
}
ul li {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grid` and `grid-auto-flow` so you set the auto-placement to `column`, check the following snippet:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 125px);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
</ul>
```